# I need to select from table where createdAt between time + 1h ahead?

Tags: sql

This is what I have tried:

```
SELECT *
FROM attendance
WHERE createdAt between ('2019-04-01 11:00:00' - interval '1 hour')

SELECT *
FROM attendance
WHERE createdAt BETWEEN '2019-04-01 11:00:00' AND
                        DATE_ADD('2019-04-01 11:00:00', 'INTERVAL 1 hour')
```

Please provide help, thanks.

Comment: (1) Tag your question with the database you are using.  (2) Provide sample data and desired results.  (3) 1 hour ahead of *what*?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
WHERE createdAt >= '2019-04-01 11:00:00' and
      createdAt < '2019-04-01 11:00:00' + interval 1 hour
```

This is MySQL syntax, based on your using `date_add()`, a MySQL function.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need quotes in the `interval` statement:

```
SELECT *
FROM attendance
WHERE createdAt BETWEEN '2019-04-01 11:00:00' AND
                        DATE_ADD('2019-04-01 11:00:00', INTERVAL 1 hour)
```